# VGA output looks smudgy

Tags: laptop, vga, external-display

I am using `Windows 8.1` on a `Lenovo G 580` with an `Intel HD 4000` graphics chip.
The external monitor I use is a `HP Z24i` and my problem is not only the max resolution that can not be reached (1920x1200, only 1600x1200 possible) but the quality of the display, which looks smudgy.

I have updated the graphics driver and used the Display Manager from HP, which did not help. There are also no Windows updates in queue to be installed. Driver wise my notebook is up to date.

[image]

Is there a way go to fix this problem?

Comment: Don’t use VGA. ;) Most VGA ports today are rather low-quality and cannot even reach VGA’s limits.

Comment: I have no problem with a 1920x1080 external display on my G580 using HDMI.

Comment: This question shows little or no research effort. Please read [ask], then update your question to include some details like, what you have tried or researched; if you have checked the manufacturer web site for support article; if there are any updates to Windows and drivers, for the graphics card and the display, that need to be installed; how long this has been going on (did it work before).

Comment: @CharlieRB, I updated my question.